# Effect of Changing polling time in hid interrupt transfer

Tags: lpc, hid

I have interfaced a HID bar-code scanner with LPC2468 using interrupt transfer. The polling interval which i receive(from bar-code) in the Endpoint Descriptor is 10 ms. What will happen if i increase or decrease this polling interval.

Comment: Apparently (according to [this datasheet](http://rapidlibrary.com/source.php?file=ulcbvwwrzbi89on&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.posforindia.com%2Fbrochures%2FTVSElectronics_BS_C101_star_Handheld.pdf&sec=46a41186b160ea84)) it can scan up to 330 times per second.

Comment: @PeterJ: Some scanners are good at picking up moving objects.  There would be some applications where one might want to catch the barcodes of objects that are zooming by on a conveyor or transport, and some conveyors/transports may have things zooming along at pretty incredible speeds. (though to be sure, I wouldn't normally expect a *handheld* device to be humanly-held near such a high-speed conveyor running at speed).

Comment: If one has a scanner which is permanently mounted to watch a high-speed conveyor, using a 10ms polling interval rather than 1ms will add a random delay of up to 9ms before an object can be reported.  That wouldn't be an issue if one were hand-pointing the scanner at barcodes for purposes of logging them, but could be a problem if the barcodes were being used in "real time" to e.g. route objects on a conveyor.  Even if the conveyor only handles one object per 100ms, a diverter may need to be triggered within a 20ms window.  An extra 9ms timing uncertainty won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you poll if more/less frequently, assuming it is ready to send data, then it will simply be a case of receiving data more or less frequently.

I'm not sure if you have read this [programming manual](http://rapidlibrary.com/source.php?file=ulzr9fffbci89on&url=http://www.tvs-e.in/pos/drivers/BS-C101-Star-Programming-Guide.pdf&sec=e01b730a6afa7f16), but if you haven't then you should. It appears (at a glance) that it is configured using the barcodes themselves (as opposed to a message from the PC.
All the configuration barcodes are there, and there is a section on changing the inter-message delay. I would try using these (set delay to 0 between messages), poll at your desired speed (up to 1 / 330 = ~3ms polling interval) and let us know how it goes.

Here is a clip of some relevant settings in the "General Configuration" section (note the "start of configuration" and "end of configuration" barcodes):

[image: Delay Configuration]

Comment: Can some data get lost due to overwriting or other reason if i increase polling interval

Comment: Not at the USB level, no - the device should just respond with a NAK to tell the PC to wait if it is not ready to send more data yet.

Comment: +1, "*not sure if you have read this programming manual*"